# Python Selenium image size

Tags: python, image, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How do I get the size of an image with selenium ?

Finding the image is simple :

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
```

But I didn't find anywhere how to get its size (not dimensions, size in bytes or kilobytes).

Answer (score 0):

You can download the image

```
with open('file.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(driver.find_element_by_xpath('path').screenshot_as_png)
```

and find size

```
os.path.getsize("filepath")
```

Comment: @Elyes Lounissi Did any of the answers work for you? If so consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[**size**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.size) attribute returns the size of the element.

As an example to print the size of the [Google Home Page](https://www.google.com/) ***Search Box*** you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).size)
```

Console Output:

```
{'height': 34, 'width': 487}
```

Comment: Didnt the question ask for size as in gigs and bytes?

Comment: Hmm. I should have been explicit that Selenium won't be able to do that.

Comment: yeah, but we can still download the file and use os to get the file size